# Alternative for ZonedDateTime and ChronoUnit to be used in JDK 7

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I wrote this line of code using **JDK 8** classes ChronoUnit and ZonedDateTime

```
            // if no timestamp was present, calculate difference between last and this date
 timestamp = pos.getFirstDateStamp().until(datestamp, ChronoUnit.MILLIS) / (double) 1000;
```

but, the branch is being compiled using JDK 7, hence I am facing issues and I'd like to know the replacement classes for these.

I did try `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` but `until()` is a part of `ZonedDateTime` and there seems to be issues with it.

Comment: There is a backport of these classes for Java 7: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Back-port

Much of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

By the way, no need to divide by 1,000 as seen in the Question’s example code. If you want a count of whole seconds elapsed between a pair of `ZonedDateTime` objects, specify [`ChronoUnit.SECONDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#SECONDS) as your `TemporalUnit`.

```
long secondsElapsed = start.until( stop , ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```